# ID1038: The AudienceRestrictionCondition was not valid because the specified Audience is not present in AudienceUris

Tags: c#, adfs

In trying to create my own SAML bearer token (simulating a 3rd party)

```
var descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor();
descriptor.AppliesToAddress = "what-should-I-put-here";
```

and exchange it for a JWT from ADFS, ADFS is giving the error

```
ID1038: The AudienceRestrictionCondition was not valid because the specified Audience is not present in AudienceUris
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers on the internet point you to setting entries in `app.config` but this was a red herring for this scenario.

The correct AudienceUri is your ADFS server with a particular path:

```
descriptor.AppliesToAddress = "http://my-really-frustrating-adfs-server/adfs/services/trust"
```